# Ciclomatic dependency and shared and weak pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have the following scenario:

[image]

However, I'm having some memory problems, since my `Dispatcher` seems to be getting deleted before its sent to `Window`.

A pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
class Kernel
{
    shared_ptr<Window> window;
    shared_ptr<Dispatcher> dispatcher;
}

class Window
{
    weak_ptr<Dispatcher> dispatcher;
}

class Dispatcher
{}
```

How can I correctly use smart pointers to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem with peace of code? In your scheme the Kernel must keep all objects, as the result the Window and the Dispatcher will be alive as long as the Kernel is alive.

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: In your code there is no problem. Simply add forward declaration before Kernel for both Window and Dispatcher classes.

Comment: How exactly is the `Dispatcher` sent to `Window`?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote example http://cpp.sh/8dkv7

As you can see your code is correct:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>

  class Dispatcher;
  class Window;

  class Kernel
  {
  public:
    std::shared_ptr<Window> window;
    std::shared_ptr<Dispatcher> dispatcher;
  };

  class Window
  {
  public:
    std::weak_ptr<Dispatcher> dispatcher;
  };

  class Dispatcher
  {
  };

  int main()
  {
    Kernel k;
    k.window = std::make_shared<Window>();
    k.dispatcher = std::make_shared<Dispatcher>();
    k.window->dispatcher = k.dispatcher;
    if( auto dispatcher = k.window->dispatcher.lock() ) {
        std::cout << "ok\n"; // i see ok, what about you?
    }
  }
```

Comment: It compiles fine, but it leaks once I try to access the `Dispatcher` from the `Window`

Comment: @DanielRibeiro can you show the prove that dispatcher is dead?